# No POST No Bios Random Characters on mothers display

Tags: motherboard, hardware-failure, bsod, intel-pentium

I was playing a youtube video and suddenly my screen pixelated with random characters and music stopped.
I tried to restart but the motherboard screen displayed with some horizontal lines and pixelated characters and didn't go forward.
I tried to restart again then there was NO POST, NO BIOS.
The processor's cooling fans rotate and hdd also rotates
I tried everything, reseating but still the problem persists.
It rarely starts windows on safe mode but crashes after a few minutes.
Sometimes the after displaying starting windows it goes to blue screen of death
I have an Intel pentium dual core e5500 on zebronics g41-d3 with 2gb ram and windows 7.
Motherboard was replaced just 3 years ago
I know it is obsolete but I can't buy a new one before 6 months.
[][1]

Here's the picture
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1ZSh.jpg